# 2 grouping variables using svyboxplot

Tags: plot, boxplot, survey

I would like to know how to add a second grouping variable (e.g. gender) when using svyboxplot and different colours for that second grouping variable, in the following code to have something similar to the attached image[enter image description here][1]:

svyboxplot(variable ~ factor(country),design, all.outliers = FALSE, cex.axis = 1.5, cex.main = 2)

Thank you in advance.

Best wishes,
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZRqk.png